# Issues with json_encode array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am having issues with my JSON_encode and jQuery, I am getting it to post the full array with the following code, but I can't get it to echo just the one array I need.

```
$.get("/indexget.php", { page: "goals" },function(data) {
$('#bodyContentStuff').text(data);
```

Full jQuery code

```
$("#navLinkGoals").click(function () {
    $("#bodyTitleBar").text("Goals");
    $.get("/indexget.php", { page: "goals" },function(data) {
        $('#bodyContentStuff').text(data);
    }
);
```

Full PHP code

```
if($_REQUEST['page'] = 'goals'){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE page='indexGoals'") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $message = $row['message'];
}
echo json_encode(array("content"=>"$message"));
```

I am sort of a noob with programming, but the site is http://www.gronge.com if you'd like to see what it is doing, just click the goals link.

Edit: Oh, I have also tried

```
$('#bodyContentStuff').text(data['content']);
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you logged the `data` variable? What does it log? Also: `mysql_*` is deprecated, steer clear and start using PDO. But I think you meant to assign `$row[0]['message']` to the `$message` variable. If memory serves me well, `mysql_*` always returns either an array of assoc arrays, or an array of arrays.

While we're on the subject: JavaScript doesn't have assoc arrays, only objects, so rather then accessing the data like `data['content']`, use `data.content`. The bracket notation is there for convenience, so you can use the value of a variable as property name (without eval), which is *EVIL*, of course.

Comment: Using data.content brings back nothing. Using (data) brings back {"content":"It works!"}.

Comment: Your memory does not serve you well. `mysql_fetch_array()` returns a one-dimensional array. What's confusing you is that this array has BOTH numeric and associative keys (unless you use the optional second argument to specify MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_NUM to select just one of them).

Comment: @Alcapwn: in which case try: `data = JSON.parse(date);` before `.text(data.content);` and you're all set (it's still a string, and needs to be parsed before you can access it as an object

Comment: It was multiple issues but I now have it working! data = JSON.parse(data); worked on removing the "s. And echo json_encode($message); worked on removing the other stuff, thank you so much!

Comment: @Barmar, you're right, should've read the man pages before making assumptions. In my defence: `mysql_*` _is_ deprecated, I haven't used it in years, since php5.1 actually

Comment: @Alcapwn: since you are using jQuery, best replace that `JSON.parse()` call with `$.parseJSON(data);`. Older IE's (IE<9) don't have native `JSON` support, so you either have to include json2.js for them (json.org), but jQ fixes this X-browser issue... just so you know: still ~+10% IE8 users on the planet, and no known cure for stupidity...

Comment: Also you probably don't need to jsonparse at all if you tell your get function you expect a json object by putting 'json' as the format (as explained below)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried putting ", 'json'" like so:

```
$.get("/indexget.php", { page: "goals" },function(data) {
    $('#bodyContentStuff').text(data.content);
}, 'json')
```

without that jquery makes an intelligent guess as to what the format is...

and as mentioned it should be data.content

and as mentioned use console.log(data) to see what data really is (maybe a string while it should be a json object?)

Comment: And the guess is based on what the PHP sends as the `Content-type` header. So the other option is to add `header("Content-type: application/json");` to the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

If that was a verbatim paste there is a missing closing parenthesis on the call to $.get

```
$("#navLinkGoals").click(function () {
    $("#bodyTitleBar").text("Goals");
    $.get(
        "/indexget.php",
        {
            page: "goals"
        },
        function(data) {
            $('#bodyContentStuff').text(data);
        }
    ); // <== Right here
);
```

(Code reformatted to highlight difference)

Just noticed a potential issue with the PHP:

```
if($_REQUEST['page'] = 'goals'){ //<== are you assigning or comparing?
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content WHERE page='indexGoals'") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    $message = $row['message'];
}
echo json_encode(array("content"=>"$message"));
```

Comment: I missed the last line on accident.

Answer (score 0):

instead of get use $.post

```
 $("#navLinkGoals").click(function () {
   $("#bodyTitleBar").text("Goals");
    $.post("/indexget.php", { page: "goals" },function(data) {
    $('#bodyContentStuff').text(data);
}
);
```

Comment: That actually didn't change any of the actions at all. :) Still have the issue with it posting the full array ({"content":"It works!"}).

Comment: Just dump your `$row` variable, to ensure you're accessing the data correctly

Answer (score -2):

Also on your php:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

And not mysql_fetch_array, if you want to use the `$row['message']` notation.

Comment: No true. By default `mysql_fetch_array()` returns an array with both indexed and associative keys.

Comment: True I just read. But for a strange reason when I use it on my server php it returns nothing, unless noted MYSQL_BOTH, or MYSQL_ASSOC on mysql_fetch_array :/